# How to call PowerShell switch case from CSV input

Tags: powershell, csv

I have PowerShell script with a `switch` statement, I am trying to import CSV input to the script along with the required variables that will be used with in the switch case statement. One of the row will have the switch case no to be called.

[image]

```
Import-Csv $path
switch ($_.caseid) {
    1 {
        # task goes here
    }
    2 {
        # task goes here
    }
    3 {
        # task goes here
    }
}
```

If the number matches it should execute the respective block and delete the executed row from the CSV, if the field is empty or incorrect values it should ignore the row and go to other row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the `Import-Csv` and `switch` statements with a `ForEach-Object`:

```
Import-Csv $path | ForEach-Object {
    switch ($_.caseid) {
        1 {
            # task goes here
        }
        2 {
            # task goes here
        }
        3 {
            # task goes here
        }
    }
}
```